# Merge 2 PowerShell commands to 1

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have a powershell commands to list all AD computers last logon date

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {enabled -eq $true} -properties * | select Name, LastLogonDate | Sort LastLogondate -Descending  | Export-csv c:\co.csv
```

and the other command that lists out all the Ad computer

```
dsquery * domainroot -filter "(&(objectCategory=computer)(operatingSystem=Windows XP*))" -limit 1000 > c:\XP_Machines.txt
```

So if we can filter all xp computers and last logon we can list out all the xp computers that are not used and upgrade the one that we being used

Comment: Those are not "2 PowerShell commands". That is one powershell cmdlet and one dsquery.exe call.

Comment: These helped me https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/92a32ecc-cc33-4904-bd10-612236516e8c/active-directory-query-for-active-xp-machines?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: you just need to put the filter of your dsquery into the filter of your `get-adcomputer`, then you will achieve your goal

Answer (score 3):

Since there is an AD Attribute for OperatingSystem, you can directly add this to the filter of your command:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {(enabled -eq $true) -AND (OperatingSystem -like "*XP*")} -properties LastLogonDate,OperatingSystem | select Name, LastLogonDate, OperatingSystem | Sort LastLogondate -Descending  | Export-csv c:\co.csv
```

This will get computers that are enabled and have Windows XP installed.

Comment: As a best practice, however, you shouldn't use "-Properties *".  Only return the properties you need.  Otherwise, you're putting extra overhead on your server that could be put to better use. Run Get-AdComputer without the -Properties parameter to see what's returned by default, then add in what you need like "-Properties lastLogondate,name,operatingSystem"

Comment: I have to admit, i am very lazy... but of course your are right, i changed my answer and replaced the wildcard by the needet properties.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by Tobias, a different notation:

```
$Filter = {(Enabled -eq $True) -and (OperatingSystem -like 'Windows XP*')}
$Properties = 'Enabled','LastLogonDate','OperatingSystem','Name'
$ResultSetSize = '3'
Get-ADComputer -Filter $Filter -Properties $Properties -ResultSetSize $ResultSetSize `
 | Select-Object -Property 'Name','LastLogonDate' `
 | Sort-Object -Property 'LastLogonDate'

Name     LastLogonDate      
----     -------------      
PC12345  10-02-2015 09:55:41 
PC67890  23-11-2015 08:40:49
PCX0000  12-01-2016 15:23:29
```